# Как переместить файл?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть два метода: поиск и сортировка.

Поиск:

```
public void Search()
        {
            title = title_tb.Text;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.DefaultExt = "fb2";
            ofd.Filter = "fb2 files (*.fb2)|*.fb2|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (result.HasValue == true)
            {
                // Open document                
                filename = ofd.FileName;                
                title_tb.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);
            }
        }
```

Я нахожу файл определенного формата, в дальнейшем его необходимо переместить в другую папку.

```
 private void SortClick_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //for sorting pb2
            title = title_tb.Text;
            path = Link_tb.Text;
            subpath = author_tb.Text;
            seriespath = SeriesOfBooks_tb.Text;


            string mydir = $@"{path}\{subpath}\{seriespath}";
            if (!Directory.Exists(mydir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(mydir);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SeriesOfBooks_tb.Text))
            // **переместить в папку seriespath**

        }
```

Если SeriesOfBooks_tb.Text не пустой, то выбранный файл добавляется в папку с названием, которое написано в SeriesOfBooks_tb.Text. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.File.Move(Path.Combine(mydir, title_tb.Text), Path.Combine(SeriesOfBooks_tb.Text, title_tb.Text));
```

Comment: вы, наверное, ошиблись?

Comment: @ConvertToNULL, да